# Create Random White Rectangle/Array into Image/Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, image, matrix

I have an image which is saved as a matrix in Python (512x512).
Now I want to add some random rectangle with constant size to simulate some missing region.
Usually I would create a random index within the size of the image and use a nested loop to create a 5x5 sized array with value 255 (= white in Python).
I would need another loop to create a specific amount of rectangles.
To sum up I need 3 loops:

```
for (0,amountOfRec):
    startPoint = (randomIndex1,randomIndex2)
         for (0,sizeOfRec)        #jump to next row
              for (0,sizeOfRec)   #create a row with value 255
```

This way seems very naive. Isn't there a better way without the use of 3 nested loops?

Comment: How do you store your matrix? Is it just plain python nested list of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dealing with large matrices, you should be using [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which enables you to use vectorized operations, among many other benefits.

Assuming your image is gray-scale (or has just a single RGB channel) and is represented in a straightforward nested array format, you can try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

#Generate random "image" (replace this with your original image)
img = np.random.randint(0,256, size=512**2).reshape(512,512)

#Make white box
box = np.array([255]*5*5).reshape(5,5)

#Generate random coordinates
x, y = np.random.randint(0,512-5, size=2)

#Replace original image with white box
img[x:x+5, y:y+5] = box
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Do you have an idea to make diagonals in a similiar way with different "thickness"?

Comment: You can use `np.diagonal` with offsets depending on the thickness.

Comment: By the way, if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.